# Getting Yum error '[Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid' even after setting sslverify=false

Tags: yum, centos6

I have to update yum libraries in CentOS 6.

I keep getting error- '[Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid.'

I have marked sslverify=false in yum.conf file. I have marked sslverify=0 in repo file and when I check using yum-config-manager it shows my sslverify configuration as False.